# Hostgator: laravel web application when I login it always redirects me back to login again

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, hosting

I have a web application developed using `laravel4 (PHP , MySql)`

Every time I try to login with correct credentials it redirects me back to login again

I don't know where is the problem. The same project is working properly on another hosting and on `localhost`

The server support couldn't help me :((